# Is there a way to disable FullDebugMode for a class or unit?

Tags: delphi, fastmm

We want to enable flag FullDebugMode of FastMM4 in an internal build that we use for testing the application. But when we enable it, the app raise an exception of "out of memory" in a form that uses the TDCInfoTree component. The form is critical for the application. I dont have the source code of the component, and from my research, it contains a lot of "dirty" memory operations. We cant change the component at this moment.

So there is the question: is there a way to disable FullDebugMode for a unit or class?

Comment: Perhaps what is really going on is that your program has bugs that FastMM has located

Comment: I have encountered `EOutOfMemoryException` in FullDebugMode of FastMM, and it was caused - or related to - issues FastMM detected. E.g the logfile read _"FastMM has detected an error during a free block scan operation. FastMM detected that a block has been modified after being freed."_.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to disable FullDebugMode for a unit or class?

No there is not.